# Is there any extension of "statistical limit functional"?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hahn-banach-theorem

$c=$The set of all real convergent sequences

$l_\infty=$The set of all real bounded sequences

Clearly $c\subset l_\infty$

$f:c\to \mathbb R$ is called limit functional defined by $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$

There exist infinitely many extensions of $f$ to $l_\infty$.
From here main concept of [Banach Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit) functional comes.

With the help of this Banach limits the notion of [almost convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_convergent_sequence) is defined.

**My Question :** What happens if we take extensions of the statistical limit functional $g$?

(where $g:st\to \mathbb R$ is defined by $g(x)=stat\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$)

Here, $st=$ The set of all bounded statistically convergent sequences.

May we define a new kind of convergence in this approach? Is it not available in literature?